# Will Flat Design cause slow loading of page

Tags: django, twitter-bootstrap, web, flat

Sorry for this dumb question, but I am new to web development.

I would like to know if there is any way to load a section of a web page first (as a web developer). e.i priortizing which section loads first?

I want to keep all the common sections of a website (like contact us, about us, login, features, etc.) on one flat page design like [this one](http://startbootstrap.com/templates/grayscale/), but this seems to take some time to load the page. Is there a way to 1st load only the first section and then behind the scenes load other sections?

Do you think having flat design will slow down the page as all the images/scripts of all sections are on one page? Or Do you think its better to have these sections in separate pages (but then, we lose flat design style)?

Thanks,

FYI: I donno think this is language dependent, but I am using Django as backend and Bootstrap as frontend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It really depends on how much content and the type of content you have. IMO I would just leave it as one page as you don't have too much content by the looks of it but its up to you.

However want your web page to load faster here are some possibly useful links:

[How to prioritize visible content for page speed](http://www.feedthebot.com/pagespeed/prioritize-visible-content.html)

[Google PageSpeed Rules](https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/best-practices/rules_intro)

Comment: Thanks... these are really good links. This is what I was looking for

Comment: Please mark the question as answered if it has answered your question.